# IOS Model, Database, Networking testing without View & Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I think of my ios app as having three levels:

- Top: View & Controller
- Middle: Model, Database, Networking
- Bottom: Infrastructure classes that don't depend on anything (e.g. a thread safe NSDictionary)

I unit test the top level with XCTest tests using XCUIApplication.
I unit test the bottom level with XCTest tests that don't use XCUIApplication.

I can't figure out how a good way to test the middle level.

These tests need a XCUIApplication, but they can be triggered by taking action with the GUI. I can build these tests into the application and trigger them with notifications. However I don't want to ship these tests with the app and I think there must be better way.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Except for views, I do all tests using Unit Tests. The key is to mock dependencies. I have written a [blog post](http://swiftandpainless.com/another-approach-to-stubbing-nsurlsession-with-dependency-injection/) about how to do that for networking code.